# add team foundation server name or URL

Tags: server-name

I downloaded Microsoft Test Manager 2010. But when I start it I should enter the Team Foundation Server name or URL. I read few articles about this problem, but I didn't find the tfs name. Can somebody suggest me what to do to find it?
tnx in advance

Comment: I tried this tutorial but at the 2nd step, I couldn't open instance of Visual Studio. This option isn't active to click. Can somebody to suggest me about my problem   onhttp://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/connect-vs/